# Assign name to seat and display in array

Tags: c++, arrays, assign

I'm having a problem assigning users to an array and then displaying the array. Typical 'flight seat-assign' program. Any help would be fantastic, as I am seriously stuck.

I haven't been getting any errors when compiling so I'm assuming I'm not too far off? code as follows.

Note, classes in separate header files.

```
// Flight Class - Scotia 2
// Contains information on seating (array), space available and return to menu option.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "booking.h"

using namespace std;

class Flight
{

public:

    public:
    struct Seat
        {
            int Available;
            string fullName;
        };// End of struct

// Structure for seat plan (24 spaces available)
    struct Seat seatArray[4][6];

    void seatPlan()
    {   //------
        cout << "Scotia Airlines Seating Plan\n";
        cout << "------------------------\n";
        cout << " 1D  2D  3D  4D  5D  6D\n";
        cout << " 1C  2C  3C  4C  5C  6C\n";
        cout << "                       \n";
        cout << " 1B  2B  3B  4B  5B  6B\n";
        cout << " 1A  2A  3A  4A  5A  6A\n";
        cout << "------------------------\n\n\n";
        //------
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<6;j++)
                {
                if (seatArray[i][j].Available == 0)
                cout << seatArray[i][j].fullName << "=" << i+1;

                else
                cout << "Seating Plan is unavailable";
                break;
                }
        }// End of for loop
    }// End of seatPlan function

};// End of Flight class
```

Here is my booking class also, as I'm sure it'll help identify a problem...

```
//Booking class - Scotia Airlines
//This class will reserve a seat for passenger

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Booking{

public:
    struct Seat
        {
            int Available;
            string fullName;
        };// End of struct

// Structure for seat plan (24 spaces available)
    struct Seat seatArray[4][6];

//variables for taking in customer details, calculating ticket cost (inc discounts) and adding details to system
    public:
    string fName, sName, busName, fullName;
    int age, livesAt;
    float discount, tickPrice, tCost;

    void addBooking()

    {
    cout << "\tBooking Menu \n\n";
    cout << "Please select ticket type: \n";
    cout << "1- Business \n";
    cout << "2- Western Isles \n";
    cout << "3- Ordinary \n";
    cin >> livesAt;

    // This will be used to calc total cost for each passenger dependant on ticket type
                    if(livesAt == 1)
                        {
                            discount = 0.75;
                            cout << "Please enter your business name\n";
                            cin >> busName;
                        }

                        else if (livesAt == 2)
                            {
                            discount = 0.90;
                            }

                        else
                            {
                            discount = 1.0;
                            };

    // Calculation - Standard ticket price is 60 Beans
                tickPrice = 60.0;
                tCost = (tickPrice * discount);


            bool booked = false;
                for(int i = 0; i < 4 && !booked; i++)
                    {
                        for(int j = 0; j < 6 && !booked; j++)
                        {
                            if(seatArray[i][j].Available == 1)
                            {
                                cout << "Please enter your first name \n";
                                cin >> fName;
                                cout << "Please enter your second name \n";
                                cin >> sName;
                                fullName == fName + " " + sName;
                                seatArray[i][j].fullName = fullName;
                                booked = true;
                                    // Message on screen for customer displaying cost of flight
                                cout << "*******************************\n";
                                cout << "\tBooking for " << fName + " " + sName << " confirmed.\n";
                                cout << "\tTotal cost = " << tCost << " GBP.\n";
                            }//end of if
                        }//end of for2
                    }//end of for1


    }// End of addBooking function
};// End of Booking class
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the program doing wrong? What is causing you to ask this question?

Comment: There is just a bunch of code and a very vague description of the problem... Did you try to debug?

Comment: The `break` statement in the `seatPlan` function looks out of place. It causes the inner loop to run only once.

Comment: Rather than using `i` and `j` as variables, I suggest renaming them as `row` and `column`, which would make your program easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some errors I have spotted:

1. First of all you never mark a seat as not available. Add this to your add booing function.
2. Second the else in the second for in seatPlan should be in the else I believe.
3. You don't need a semi-column after an else statement(in the else when setting discount to 1.0)

As you never mention what are the errors you are getting this is as good as I can get. Hope this answer helps.

Comment: Sorry folks. I did forget to highlight the problem. When i debug I'm not given an error. That's where it's going wrong. What i was trying to do here have a passenger reserve a seat on a 24 seater plane. It takes in the passengers details i.e first name, last name and assigns it to a seat on the plane. It lets me compile and run, but when I select to view the plane seat plan from the menu, It cout's the layout, then the error message "seat plan is unavaiable" 3 times. Sorry I forgot to include all that the first time! :(